# Collapse factor levels into missing levels

Tags: r, levels, forcats

I would like to have `"Dont know"` and `"Refuse"` as missing, but assigning it to `NULL` does not seem to do the trick.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- tibble(
  a = factor(c("Yes", "No", "Dont know", "Yes",  "Refuse", "No",
               "Dont know", "Yes", "No", "Dont know", "Refuse"))
)

mydata %>% 
  mutate(a = fct_collapse(a, NULL = c("Dont know", "Refuse"))) %>%
  count(a)

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   a         n
#   <fct> <int>
# 1 NULL      5
# 2 No        3
# 3 Yes       3
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you tell us the package versions of: forcats, dplyr, tibble and pillars? I'm on dplyr 1.0.10 and forcats 0.51 and I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: forcats_1.0.0 and dplyr_1.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `forcats v1.0.0`, you should use `fct_na_level_to_value`:

```r
mydata %>% 
  mutate(a = fct_na_level_to_value(a, extra_levels = c("Dont know", "Refuse"))) %>%
  count(a)

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   a         n
#   <fct> <int>
# 1 No        3
# 2 Yes       3
# 3 NA        5
```

Comment: Interesting! Initially the fct_collapse would do the thing....

Comment: @DarrenTsai Interesting, thats the reason I can't reproduce the issue with forcats 0.51!

Comment: forcats_1.0.0 and dplyr_1.1.0